# Memcached or any other FedRAMP certified?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, aerospike

I have a need to add a centralized caching store for one of my projects serving the government. Does anyone know if memcached (or any other store) is FedRAMP certified ?

I know (:think) AWS ElastiCache is FedRAMP certified, however, I "can't" use a Cloud Store for the Cache as the software can be installed isolated from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear so on the [FedRAMP website](https://marketplace.fedramp.gov/#/products?status=Compliant;In%20Process;FedRAMP%20Ready&sort=productName). Also, I believe FedRAMP only applies to [SAAS, PAAS, and IAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) products.

Comment: I'm a newbie concerning FedRAMP and would highly appreciate a little more insight about non-{S,P,I} AAS Products or maybe a link where I can read some information about them. Tried searching google, but didnt hit anything relevant probably cause of the formatting of the phrase. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did that clarify the concern?